# What type of password hash

Tags: hash, passwords, password-hash

!MJXAy.... (41 characters, A-Z a-z 0-9)
I have a list of passwords from an older web app, but no longer have the source for creating / verifying the hash.
I think it may have been a django app, but cant be sure. 
Im looking for either the type of hash , or a link to source so i can validate logins.

Any thoughts / suggestions?

Comment: If the old program used a salt and you have no idea what that salt might be, then you might want to just ask all the users to reset their passwords from an email or something.  There is a fair number of common hashing alorighthms, which you could try given you know a plaintext password and its hash.

Comment: There is no salt, i think i may have to just wipe the password set and start from scrath. My google searches haven't returned any hashes that start with !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might simply have 40-character hashes that have been "disabled".

`!` and `*` are often placed at the beginning or end of a hash to reversibly "disable" accounts (because those characters never appear in most hashes, thereby by making any hash containing them impossible to match).

If the account ever needs to be reactivated, the obviously invalid "disabling" character can simply be removed, restoring the original password *without having to know the original password or interact with the user*.

If *all* of the hashes start with an exclamation point, perhaps all of the hashes were disabled on purpose for some reason.

And for what it's worth, the two Django formats that I'm aware of look like this (from 
[the Hashcat example-hashes page](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes), both plaintexts 'hashcat'):

```
Django (PBKDF2-SHA256): 
pbkdf2_sha256$20000$H0dPx8NeajVu$GiC4k5kqbbR9qWBlsRgDywNqC2vd9kqfk7zdorEnNas=

Django (SHA-1):
sha1$fe76b$02d5916550edf7fc8c886f044887f4b1abf9b013
```

Both of these are salted and don't seem to match your character set. It's possible that your hash is a custom one, with the final step being a base64 conversion (but without the trailing `=`?).

The closest I can see are an ASCII MD5 hash converted to base64 and a binary SHA26 hash converted to base64, but both of those are 44 characters.

Your best bet may be to trim off the `!` and try to verify them with [mdxfind](https://hashes.org/mdxfind.php), which will try many different kinds and chains of hashing,  encoding, and truncation.

Comment: your spot on, on all counts. After some further digging, those database rows were not activated. As in they have a activation_key column that has a value. Django does save all the useful items in the field.  Thank you.